# Unable to freeze model trained using keras and tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am new to keras and tensorflow.
I have trained a model using keras and saved it using saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder

I have .pb file and variables folder with two files variables.index and variables.data-00000-of-00001

Now I am trying to freeze the graph and variables but getting following error

```
google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 1:1 : Expected identifier or number, got.
```

please help

Comment: did you manage to solve it?